# Runtime Exception:Invalid version (expected 2, but 60) or the data in not in 'javabin' format in solr

Tags: java, solr, runtimeexception

I am getting a runtime exception when I am making the following simple call to ping my solr at localhost.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException, IOException
    {
        String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/#";
        HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(url);
        solrServer.ping();

    }
```

The exception log is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version (expected 2, but     60) or the data in not in 'javabin' format
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:109)
    at         org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BinaryResponseParser.processResponse(BinaryResponseParser.    java:41)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:407)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:180)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.SolrPing.process(SolrPing.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.ping(SolrServer.java:293)
    at com.tradus.LocalSolrDataAdd.main(LocalSolrDataAdd.java:26)
```

Can someone explain how we can get rid of this apparently very weird error.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Java when compiling the client as you're using when you're running Solr? Which version of Solr are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version of the code that seems to match your stacktrace:

- http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj/4.5.0/org/apache/solr/common/util/JavaBinCodec.java/

The code seems to be trying to check the version number of response to the "ping" request.  Your Solr client is getting a response that it doesn't understand.  And my guess is that something has been misconfigured ... or you have given it the wrong URL.

Getting a version number of "60" instead of "2" seems unlikely.  My guess is that the "60" is actually an `<` character ... which suggests to me that you have some XML or HTML rather than a binary response.  In the latter case, it could be a page from the application container telling you that it doesn't understand your request ... or something.

I suggest that you check the server log files to see what requests it is getting.  If that fails, try to capture the network traffic to / from your client.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually because the different version between the solr client and solr server.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `#` is wrong:

```
String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/#";//  [#] is wrong!!!
```

This should be the correct usage:

```
String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1; is ok!!!

HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(url);

solrServer.ping();
```